# In Typescript, how can I pass an array of (keyof Object) without having to hardcode it every time? How on earth can this be so complicated?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, constants, keyof

So I have the following very simple `User` interface and `getUserById()` method that retrieves a type-safe user that includes only the specified fields/properties (what is usually called a projection):

```
interface User {
  _id: string,
  username: string,
  foo: string
}

function getUserById<Field extends keyof User>(
  id: string,
  fields: Field[]
): Pick<User, Field> {   
  // In real-life an object with only the specified fields/properties is returned
  // and the id and fields parameters are both used as part of this process
  return {} as User; 
}
```

This is working perfectly as demonstrated in the usage bellow, because `user1` is fully type-safe and accessing `user1.foo` will raise a Typescript error:

```
const user1 = getUserById('myId', ['_id', 'username']);
console.log(user1); // user1 is correctly typed as Pick<User, '_id' | 'username'>
console.log(user1.foo); // We get the error: Property 'foo' does not exist. Great!
```

However now I want to do what I thought should be a fairly easy thing. As I use the `['_id', 'username']` parameter a lot of times, I want to create a `DEFAULT_USER_FIELDS` constant for it so that I can re-use it everywhere:

```
const DEFAULT_USER_FIELDS: (keyof User)[] = ['_id', 'username'];

const user2 = getUserById('myId', DEFAULT_USER_FIELDS);
console.log(user2); // user2 is INCORRECTLY typed as Pick<User, keyof User>
console.log(user2.foo); // We do NOT get any error. This is bad!
```

However as you can see, with this simple change, the type safety of `user2` is lost, and now I do not get any error when accessing `user2.foo`, which is really bad. How can I solve this? I have tried countless things for hours and haven't really found a working solution.

Edit: [Code Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-sBnY0lGnQzHGwhQMWnZjHCcLdHAJDVrIQA) with exactly the same code where Typescript errors can be seen and played with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const DEFAULT_USER_FIELDS: ('_id' | 'username')[] = ['_id', 'username'];
```

The reason `getUserById` ever works in the first place is because `Field` will be inferred to the union of the elements of `fields`, which will be more specific than just `keyof User` (`Pick<User, keyof User>` is just `User`). Without the function call to guide inference of the list's type you have to give that type yourself.

You could avoid repeating the fields by repeating the trick from `getUserById` instead:

```
function fieldsOf<T>(): <Field extends keyof T>(fields: Field[]) => Field[] {
  return fields => fields
}

const DEFAULT_USER_FIELDS = fieldsOf<User>()(['_id', 'username']);
```

`DEFAULT_USER_FIELDS` has the same type and value either way.

Comment: That's great, thanks for both alternatives. Can you think of any way to actually use the first solution (without having to use the more complex custom `fieldsOf` generic) but be prevented from typing the wrong fields? For example if I do `const DEFAULT_USER_FIELDS: ('_id' | 'usernameee')[] = ['_id', 'usernameee'];` by mistake that will not raise any error until I actually use the constant.

Comment: If anyone finds the `fieldsOf<T>()` function difficult to read, for this particular use-case it can be simplified to `function fieldsOfUser<Field extends keyof User>(fields: Field[]) { return fields; }` with usage `const DEFAULT_USER_FIELDS = fieldsOfUser(['_id', 'username']);`

Answer (score 0):

Completely based on @HTNW's first solution, I found a way to slightly improve it so that I still have to repeat the field names but at least we have type safety in the definition of `DEFAULT_USER_FIELDS` itself:

```
const DEFAULT_USER_FIELDS: (keyof Pick<User, '_id' | 'username'>)[] = ['_id', 'username'];
```

But actually even that is still somewhat error prone because even though we cannot for example mistakenly write `usernameee` 2 times, the actual value of the array could be empty or have repeated values. After more thinking I think this is the verbose solution that would fully prevent inconsistencies between the declared compile-time types and the run-time values of the array:

```
const DEFAULT_USER_FIELDS: [
    keyof Pick<User, '_id'>,
    keyof Pick<User, 'username'>
  ] = ['_id', 'username'];
```

And finally I also found another solution that prevents the repetition without having to use a generic:

```
const DEFAULT_USER_FIELDS = ['_id', 'username'] as const;

const user2 = getUserById('myId', DEFAULT_USER_FIELDS as unknown as typeof DEFAULT_USER_FIELDS[number][]);
```